# Using wcf.js and node.js to contact a WCF service with Alexa does not work properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, wcf, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Using Alexa-sdk node.js lambda aws service wcf.js xml2js and a VB.NET Web Service.

The idea is to send in two strings to the web service and get a string in return that alexa will then speak.  Everything works until the very end where Alexa should speak the returned string.

Here is a the modified Hello World application.  Sending two strings to the WCF service works.  However console.log line after the proxy.send seems to run before the proxy line gets finished and the stringspeech variable is undefined as if the proxy line has not finished running yet.

### Code:

```
'use strict';
var Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");

// For detailed tutorial on how to making a Alexa skill,
// please visit us at http://alexa.design/build


exports.handler = function(event, context) {
var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
alexa.execute();
};

var handlers = {
'LaunchRequest': function () {
    this.emit('SayHello');
},
'HelloWorldIntent': function () {
    this.emit('SayHello');
},
'MyNameIsIntent': function () {
    this.emit('SayHelloName');
},
'SayHello': function () {
    console.log("start");
    var stringspeech;
    var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    var BasicHttpBinding = require('wcf.js').BasicHttpBinding
    , Proxy = require('wcf.js').Proxy
    , binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
    , proxy = new Proxy (binding, "http://service.menofnoblegirth.com/service1.svc")
    , message = "<Envelope xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" +
             "<Header />" +
               "<Body>" +
                 "<GetData xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>" +
                   "<value>test</value>" +
                   "<value2>test2</value2>" +
                 "</GetData>" +
                "</Body>" +
           "</Envelope>"
    proxy.send(message, "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData", function (response, ctx) {
        parseString(response, function(error, result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            var stringfun = JSON.stringify(result);
            var objectValue = JSON.parse(stringfun);
            console.log(objectValue["s:Envelope"]["s:Body"][0]["GetDataResponse"][0]["GetDataResult"][0]);
            stringspeech = objectValue["s:Envelope"]["s:Body"][0]["GetDataResponse"][0]["GetDataResult"][0];
            console.log("The variable stringspeech is now set to: " + stringspeech);

        });

    });
    console.log("The variable stringspeech is FINALLY set to: " + stringspeech);
    this.response.speak(stringspeech)
        .cardRenderer(stringspeech, stringspeech);
    this.emit(':responseReady');
},
'SayHelloName': function () {
    var name = this.event.request.intent.slots.name.value;
    this.response.speak('Hello ' + name)
        .cardRenderer('hello world', 'hello ' + name);
    this.emit(':responseReady');
},
'SessionEndedRequest' : function() {
    console.log('Session ended with reason: ' + this.event.request.reason);
},
'AMAZON.StopIntent' : function() {
    this.response.speak('Bye');
    this.emit(':responseReady');
},
'AMAZON.HelpIntent' : function() {
    this.response.speak("You can try: 'alexa, hello world' or 'alexa, ask hello world my" +
        " name is awesome Aaron'");
    this.emit(':responseReady');
},
'AMAZON.CancelIntent' : function() {
    this.response.speak('Bye');
    this.emit(':responseReady');
},
'Unhandled' : function() {
    this.response.speak("Sorry, I didn't get that. You can try: 'alexa, hello world'" +
        " or 'alexa, ask hello world my name is awesome Aaron'");
    }
};
```

### LogFile Results:

```
START RequestId: 4345330e-1c06-11e8-90fc-970a92c343fd Version: $LATEST
2018-02-27T21:36:26.067Z 4345330e-1c06-11e8-90fc-970a92c343fd Warning: Application ID is not set
2018-02-27T21:36:26.106Z 4345330e-1c06-11e8-90fc-970a92c343fd start
2018-02-27T21:36:29.789Z 4345330e-1c06-11e8-90fc-970a92c343fd The variable stringspeech is FINALLY set to: undefined
2018-02-27T21:36:30.208Z 4345330e-1c06-11e8-90fc-970a92c343fd
{
"s:Envelope": {
    "$": {
        "xmlns:s": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    },
    "s:Body": [
        {
            "GetDataResponse": [
                {
                    "$": {
                        "xmlns": "http://tempuri.org/"
                    },
                    "GetDataResult": [
                        "You entered test test2"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}

2018-02-27T21:36:30.226Z 4345330e-1c06-11e8-90fc-970a92c343fd You entered test test2
2018-02-27T21:36:30.226Z 4345330e-1c06-11e8-90fc-970a92c343fd The variable stringspeech is now set to: You entered test test2
END RequestId: 4345330e-1c06-11e8-90fc-970a92c343fd
REPORT RequestId: 4345330e-1c06-11e8-90fc-970a92c343fd Duration: 4349.27 ms Billed Duration: 4400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 48 MB
```

Answer (score 0):

The proxy.send call was running async.  To fix the problem I had to change the proxy.send line so the this.response.speak was accessible from within the proxy.send function.  It now looks like this:

```
proxy.send(message, "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData", (response, ctx) => {
    parseString(response, function(error, result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        var stringfun = JSON.stringify(result);
        var objectValue = JSON.parse(stringfun);
        console.log(objectValue["s:Envelope"]["s:Body"][0]["GetDataResponse"][0]["GetDataResult"][0]);
        stringspeech = objectValue["s:Envelope"]["s:Body"][0]["GetDataResponse"][0]["GetDataResult"][0];
        console.log("The variable stringspeech is now set to: " + stringspeech);
        console.log("The variable stringspeech is FINALLY set to: " + stringspeech);
        this.response.speak(stringspeech).cardRenderer(stringspeech, stringspeech);
        this.emit(':responseReady');

    });

});
```